# Trying to determine kWh used to run a pump on hydronic boiler

Tags: output, fluid-pump

Pump is BA Armstrong  CV 60, HP 1/12  , RPM 1725,  VOLTS 115, AMPS 2.3   SERIAL # 7802

Comment: Without knowing the actual amps (depends upon loading of the pump), you can only make an estimate.  Volts x amps x hours.

Comment: Assuming all that power information is for the input, the calculation is straight forward: 1/12HP is 63 Watts, so it's 0.063*hrs to give you kWh

Comment: Use small k for kilo and capitals like W for names then small h for time to get kWh  then estimate duty factor for best / worst case and average

Comment: just the info I was asking for - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

International standards require motors to have the mechanical output power marked on the rating plate. The motor is likely rated to produce 1/12 Hp of mechanical power. The motor slip is 1800 - 1725 = 75 RPM or 75/1800 = .0417 or 4 percent. That is one indication that the motor is not particularly efficient. The fact that the motor is a single-phase 115-volt motor is another indication of low efficiency. It is also a very low-power motor, a third indication of low efficiency. If it is running at rated load, the electrical input power that it is using is likely nearly twice the mechanical power, something like 100 watts. That estimate is an educated guess that includes a lot of uncertainly including uncertainly about the actual mechanical load on the motor.

Measuring the current will not help much because AC power is current X voltage X power factor. The power factor is likely comparable to efficiency, something like 0.6. If you really want to know the power usage, you need to measure it.  Look at [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html).

Comment: Very helpful - I assume it's not very efficient as it is very old, but runs well.